# Using continue to skip iteration in foreach from inside a swich

Tags: php, foreach, switch-statement, continue

```
$arr = array('not want to print','foo','bar');

foreach($arr as $item) {
  switch($item) {
      case 'foo':
         $item = 'bar';
         break;
      case 'not want to print':
         continue;
         break;
  }

  echo $item;
}
```

http://codepad.org/WvW1Fmmo

But "`not want to print`" is echoed. Why does continue don't apply to the foreach?

Comment: You misspelled `switch`. Is that in the real code or a copying error?

Comment: Hi, thanks; no, it's actually a sample http://codepad.org/Ytkd8x2M

Comment: 'no want to print' vs 'not want to print' - typo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php:

> **Note**: Note that in PHP the [switch](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement is considered a looping structure for the purposes of *continue*.

So use `continue 2;` to continue the loop that contains it.

You also have a mismatch between `$arr` and `case`. The first word in the array value is `no`, but you're checking for `not` in the `case`.

[Corrected codepad](http://codepad.org/oxA4nM9v)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, didn't ever heard of it. Actually my code was larger and there where no typos, I tried to reproduce a simpler version of the code, haha. Thanks again!